Lock the State on a Bug, when it's closed
We have a scenario where a closed bug has been re-opened by a dev, and a PR associated with it. I want to prevent Closed bugs from being changed, and force users to create a new (maybe cloned) bug for their new PR, so QA know there's another change that needs testing.
I tried to do with with Rules on the Bug work item type, but there's no Make read-only > State option; state isn't in the fields DDL.

How else might I prevent a transition away from Closed, on a Closed bug?

If you're going to flag a question for close, please provide a comment as to why.
